# How filter a Gridview by daterange and two textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a Gridview with a column named Date, i want to put 2 textbox to receive a date range and filter the gridview when i push a button event.

How can i do it? without using a SQL query? i guess that the best solution is using filtering property but i cant figured it out the sintaxis.

Comment: What DataSource are you using? How does your grid look like?

Comment: SQLDataSource (i am connected to an access db)... my grid looks mmm i dont understand that question.

Comment: What is your Datasource is it DataTable if it is so then you can filter data from DataTable.

Comment: Not, i made the connection directly, i didnt create a data table... just connected the Gridview with the DataSource

Comment: is it possible to have DataTable ? and then assing this datatable to Gridview datasource if it is so then u can filter records from datatable

Comment: i need the entire information of the datasource, if i made the datatable will make a repetition of objects, but i can use it as a last option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `filterexpression` in `<asp:sqldatasource>` so you can filter it like this:

```
filterexpression="date between '{0}' and '{0}'"
<filterparameters>
  <asp:controlparameter controlid="textbox" propertyname="Text" />
</filterparameters>
```

Reference is available over here: [Filter Gridview](http://forums.asp.net/p/1034014/2904713.aspx)

Comment: but if i do this, i will have a blank gridview until i fill the two textbox... i want a filled gridview and later have the posibility of filter it if the user need...

Comment: Have you read this: `don't forget to set "ConvertEmptyStringToNull"  property of ControlParameter in FilterParameters to "false"

This ensures the gridview shows all data when no text in all filter text boaxes`

Comment: you are right... but when i try to use "between" the next error appear: The expression contains unsupported operator 'Between'.

Comment: Try changing this as `filterexpression="date >= '{0}' and date <= '{0}'"`

Comment: this is getting close, but now i have another problem, my textbox is obviously string and my column datetime, and the next error appear:  Cannot perform '>=' operation on System.DateTime and System.String.

Comment: Put `#` before and after the dates that is `#'{0}'#`

Comment: noup, when i made the change this appear: Missing operand after '<=' operator...
i guess that we are missing something

Comment: Check this out: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865912/datatable-select-date-format-problem)