# selecting dates greater than from xml using C#

Tags: c#, xml, powershell, select

I am getting myself confused in Powershell in trying to use C# to fill a spreadsheet with two columns. The first is "start" and is what I need help with most. I want this to populate with dates greater than 31st July of a given year as entered as a string at the start. The below is part of what i'm using, and the whole thing is giving me a spreadsheet, but just not the dates I need. It's the line that starts $dr = $DS.Tables which I have been tampering with but to no avail.

```
$fileyear = "2017";


###Location of default DLLs
$DllsDir = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSScriptRoot,"dlls")
Write-Output "Dll Path "+$DllsDir


###Load default DLLs
foreach ($dll in [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($DllsDir,"*.dll", 
[System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories))
{
[reflection.assembly]::loadfrom($dll);
}

Write-Output "Dlls loaded";


###declare objects
$DS = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;

$DS.ReadXml($DBPath,[System.Data.XmlReadMode]::Auto);


$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable;
$dt.Columns.Add("Start");
$dt.Columns.Add("ULIN");

$dr = $DS.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Select("LearnStartDate > 
(31/07/"+$fileyear+")");

[datetime]$LearnStartDate = $dr["LearnStartDate"]




Write-Output $dt.Rows.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the date is not in the correct format. The format depends on the region your machine is configured.

I would build the date using the ISO format. Check for example this question for a reference: [DataTable.Select date format problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865912/datatable-select-date-format-problem)